# Torch.cuda.empty_cache() replacement in case of CPU only enviroment

Tags: python, pytorch

Currently, I am using PyTorch built with CPU only support. When I run inference, somehow information for that input file is stored in cache and memory keeps on increasing for every new unique file used for inference. On the other hand, memory usage does not increase if i use the same file again and again.

Is there a way to clear cache like cuda.empty_cache() in case of CPUs only.

Comment: Post the code you're using for the inference loop. Maybe the problem is something else.